# "make no sense" vs "doesn't make any sense"

Tags: meaning

I've been listening to an American podcast that the speaker said:

> I feel like somehow the Jan.6 Capital riot **doesn't make any sense to me** or maybe even better say **makes no sense** to me!

And after that she said to her guest that:

> as you know these two phrase are different with eachother.

What's the difference between these too sentences while they both have the same meaning for me as a learner, what makes them different for a native speaker?

Comment: They are equivalent. My pocket contains no money. My pocket does not contain any money.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I thought so but the second sentence of the speaker confused me.

Comment: I doubt anyone here can really "explain" why your cited speaker said ***...or maybe even better...*** Presumably at least ***he*** felt that the shorter form ***makes no sense*** was somehow more "emphatic". I'm guessing he found the capital riots ***completely*** "senseless", and he thought the shorter version conveyed that better. But of course, he's mistaken in thinking that. Both versions can be given added "oomph" with, for example, *...doesn't make any sense **at all*** and *...makes **absolutely** no sense*. But as they stand, no such distinction exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very little difference in meaning between 'makes no sense' and 'doesn't make any sense'.

**No + noun** usually makes the negative **stronger**.

You don't have any alternative. - You have **no** alternative. (**stronger**)

I don't have any money. - I have **no** money. (**stronger**)

It doesn't make any sense. - It makes **no** **sense**. (**stronger**)

He doesn't have any homework to do. - He has **no** homework to do. (**stronger**)

You didn't pay any attention to what I was saying. - You paid no attention to what I was saying.

Answer (score 1):

You can say the same thing, e.g. something is missing or absent, either with a negative verb and 'any' (it doesn't/**does not make any** sense to me) or a positive one and 'no' (it **makes no** sense to me).